# Stopping the animation and getting back to second activity

Tags: android, gif

I have a dialog box in which the gif animation gets played. I want to stop the animation after a particular amount of time and get back to the second activity. But when I am finishing the gif animation, the activity is going back to the first activity which I don't want. 
This is the code I have tried.

```
        ImageButton apple = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    apple.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Fruits.this);
            WebView view = new WebView(Fruits.this);
            view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            builder.setView(view);
            builder.create().show();
            view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/apple.gif");

            gifIsPlaying = true;

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    gifIsPlaying = false;
                    finish();
                }
            }, PLAYING_TIME_OF_GIF);

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `finish()` finishes the `Activity`. You should `dismiss()` the `Dialog` like this:

```
ImageButton apple = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
apple.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Fruits.this);
        WebView view = new WebView(Fruits.this);
        view.setLayoutParams(
                new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        builder.setView(view);
        final Dialog d = builder.create(); // save a Dialog reference here
        d.show();
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/apple.gif");

        gifIsPlaying = true;

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                gifIsPlaying = false;
                if (d.isShowing()) { // dismiss dialog if still showing
                    d.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }, PLAYING_TIME_OF_GIF);

    }
});
```